# Thunderbird запуск ссылок типа file://// через проводник

Tags: samba, explorer, thunderbird

В Thunderbird не открываются подобные ссылки в проводнике:

```
file://///samb/photos/2020/28.02%20%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A6%20jpeg
```

Пытался указать explorer.exe, однако, он запускает домашнюю директорию.
Как сделать так, чтобы ссылка открывалась при нажатии на гиперссылку?
ОС Windows

Answer (score 0):

Сделано это из-за ограничений безопасности. более детально описано тут

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work